# New order email is not sending to customer

Tags: php, email, opencart, opencart2.x

I am using **Opencart** the `2.0.1.1` version.

My store is working well to send all the emails to customer as well as admin but except the new order. When any customer placed the order then my store is not sending the mail to my customer.

I tried to use the SMTP and the MAIL option in admin side, but there is no effect to send mail to customer.

Can someone advise what can I do to troubleshoot this?

Thanks and regards,

Amal

Comment: If your all emails are working fine except order email then you have to trace your code. customer placed order mail is coded in the model -> checkout -> order.

Answer (score 0):

Use php mail function and place the below code in php.ini file of both admin and catlog

sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i;